# how to start hbase master using java code in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, default-programs

We made a .bat file by using the following code

> `#! /bin/sh
>       /home/burhan/hbase-0.94.15/bin/start-hbase.sh 
>       /home/burhan/hbase-0.94.15/bin/hbase shell`

The above code is run successfully by using the terminal and hbase is started.
But when we run the bat file by using java in eclipse its not work.Why?

We write following code in java in eclipse .

`Process p;
p=Runtime.getruntime().exec("sh -c /home/burhan/bat.sh");`